# Solve the following integral using substitution only?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can you solve the following integral using only substitution? $$\int \dfrac{dx}{\left(\sqrt{x^2-4}\right)^3}$$ I saw a solution to this which began with $x=2\sec(u)$, but is there another way to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean using only simple ("$u$") substitution? The method which began $x = 2 \sec(u)$ is called trigonometric substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution $x=t+\frac{1}{t}$ will do the job.

Integration by parts can also be used to reduce to a perhaps more familiar integral that can be trivially solved by the substitution $u=2\cosh x$.

Comment: Very Nice! How did you think to ever do that substitution? Is it a standard substitution? I hope you don't mind the questions, I'm just trying to get better at math.

Comment: It is semi-standard, comes up a lot in the few arclength questions one can integrate explicitly. It is a relative of the $\cosh t$ substitution, which is also a useful way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Another way may be arisen by setting $$x^2-4=t^2x^2$$

Comment: nice hint, hope they used it too! +1

Comment: Nice, Babak! I agree with Amzoti! +1

Comment: @Babak S:║▁ ▂ ▃ ▅N▅I▆C▇E██H▇I▆N▅T▅ ▃ ▂ ▁║✔

Answer (score 2):

One more substitution can be hyperbolic substitution.
Put $x=2\cosh{t}.$ Then $x^2-4=4\sinh^2{t},\;\;\; dx=2\sinh{t}\ dt,$ and
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2-4)^3}}=\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{\sinh{t}\ dt}{\sinh^3{t}}=\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{dt}{\sinh^2{t}}=-\frac{1}{4}\coth{t}+C.$$